# WCF methods are getting called twice when their HTTP verb is PUT or DELETE

Tags: wcf, iis

I have a WCF service with multiple endpoints which I call from AJAX/JS. Everything is working fine, except if I go to my log table.
I store every call to this wcf service in a table and I've noticed that, if the verb used to call the methods is PUT or DELETE, the method is called twice. Of course, it has no impact on data since PUT and DELETE are supposed to be idempotent (and I made the corresponding stored procedures to act as such).

Digging this problem, I have changed PUT to POST in one method and it was then only called once. Changed it back to PUT, and it was called twice again. So it can't be related to the DataContracts, as I have read in another post. I have used SVCTraceViewer and nothing unexpected appeared, except for the double calls of course.
I must also add that 
1) WebDav Publishing is NOT installed
2) I've checked in IIS and svc handlers have all verbs authorized 
Still, I'm more and more convinced it's a IIS issue, but I don't know where to look.
Any advice would be welcome.
Thanks for the time you've spent reading this post... and thinking of an solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK, found it. Thought I would post the answer : I was using Response status code 204 for put and delete successful requests. However it seems that code 204 asks the page to remain and actually request the same url a second time. Changed it to 202 : problem solved.
Best regards to stack o.